# Atof() и символ-разделитель

Tags: c++, double, локаль

Как заставить работать atof() в локали, где в качестве разделителя в числе double используется запятая, а не точка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гляньте [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1333451/276994).

Если коротко:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>

...
float value = 0.0f;
std::istringstream istr(str); // str содержит строковое представление

istr.imbue(<нужная локаль>);
istr >> value;
```

(Оберните это в функцию.)

С другой стороны, если **всё** ваше приложение работает в некоторой локали, можно просто в начале `main` вызвать `setlocale`.